# move everything after the 6th backslash up one line with sed

Tags: sed

```
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/xyz/fred-episode-110
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/abc/simon-episode-266
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/qwe/mum-episode-39
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/zxc/dad-episode-41
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/asd/bob-episode-57
```

i have many url's saved in a txt file like show above i want to move everything after the 6th backslash up one line with a sed script

the txt after the 6th backslash is the title and always different i need to select the title so i can play it

so i need it to look like this

```
fred-episode-110
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/xyz/fred-episode-110
simon-episode-266
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/abc/simon-episode-266
mum-episode-39
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/qwe/mum-episode-39
dad-episode-41
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/zxc/dad-episode-41
bob-episode-57
http://www.somesite/play/episodes/asd/bob-episode-57
```

using just sed

i can do this with awk but i want to do this with just sed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following sed command:

```
sed 'h;s@\([^/]*/\)\{6\}@@;p;x;' sed_test.txt
```

**On your input:**

[image]

**Explanations:**

- `h;` copy your pattern buffer to your hold buffer
- `s@\([^/]*/\)\{6\}@@;` delete until the 6th `/` the content of your pattern buffer
- `p;` print the pattern buffer
- `x` exchange the pattern buffer and hold buffer content
- then do the default action -> print the content of the pattern buffer

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one too

```
sed -E 's|(.*/)(.*)|\2\n&|' infile
```